# Error open camera app on Android

Tags: android, camera, runtime-error, default

Help me to fix native android camera app.
When i try to open default camera app on android i have error. In catLog i see next info

```
08-19 16:16:36.080: I/ActivityManager(239): [AppLaunch] Displayed
com.android.camera/.Camera: +1s193ms
08-19 16:16:36.080: D/ActivityManager(239): AP_PROF:AppLaunch_LaunchTime:com.android.camera/.Camera:1193:11102958
08-19 16:16:36.083: V/ActivityManager(239): Activity idle: Token{41863dc8 ActivityRecord{42428e68 com.android.camera/.Camera}}
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239): mtprof entry can not found!
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/mtprof/status: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:448)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.mtProf(ActivityRecord.java:852)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:653)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:225)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:6994)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:754)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:432)
08-19 16:16:36.084: E/ActivityManager(239):     ... 9 more
08-19 16:16:36.085: V/ActivityManager(239): Stopping ActivityRecord{422b72e8 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}: nowVisible=true waitingVisible=true finishing=false
08-19 16:16:36.085: I/InputDispatcher(239): channel '4225a2f8 Starting com.android.camera (server)' ~ abortBrokenDispatchCycle - notify=false
```

Comment: Code? Did you root or flash your device? Manufacturer and phone/tablet?

Comment: I have not root or flash my device. 6 month it work great but last time i can't open native app "camera". Phone Jiayu G2 Android 4.0. Other camera app from play market don't work too. And in the log display the same error

Comment: can You show some relevant part of code please? It seems that this could some problem with passing context..

Comment: i can't show the code because it is native (standard) google app. Error have all apps for camera from google play store. I'll have to flash the phone to fix this error?